# Calculating the types $A \times B$ and $(A \to B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I understand this is a fairly basic concept in set theory but I'm trying to understand functions in set theory and I can't seem to find an answer to my question that makes sense to me. Using these two sets as an example:

A = {0, 1} and B = {a, b, c}

x = the cartesian product (cross product)

I understand that all the types/all the elements of AxB = {(0, a),(0, b),(0, c),(1, a),(1, b),(1, c)}

But why are all the elements of A->B
{{(0, a),(1, a)},
{(0, a),(1, b)},
{(0, a),(1, c)},
{(0, b),(1, a)},
{(0, b),(1, b)},
{(0, b),(1, c)},
{(0, c),(1, a)},
{(0, c),(1, b)},
{(0, c),(1, c)}
}

My understanding was that functions have to have a "unique" mapping and in this representation, they don't seem to, it looks like (0,a) gets mapped to multiple different outputs. Also, why is the mapping AxB to AxB I imagine a function as a mapping from and element of A to an element of B is this the wrong way of thinking about it? And finally why do all the elements look like {(0,_),(1,_)}? Why is there not a 1 in the first AxB?

Thank you for any help and apologies if this is a bit of a basic question for here I just couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere else that made sense to me.

Comment: Those aren't the elements of $A\to B$... As you note, functions need to map inputs to outputs uniquely, and what you wrote doesn't do that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Functions are relations, i.e., subsets of the cartesian product such that for every element of $a$, there is precisely $1$ element in $A\times B$ such that the first coordinate is $a$.

Comment: As for "*Why is there not a $1$ in the first AxB?*"  you should remember that for *sets* the order in which elements are arranged does not matter.  $\{(0,a),(1,b)\}$ is *equal* to $\{(1,b),(0,a)\}$.  It is merely a convenience to write things in a consistent manner where the first coordinates of the tuples are always in increasing order as a way to avoid duplicate entries in the list.

Comment: In your example you have a set $A \times B$ with 6 elements; thus $2^6$ subsets, from $\emptyset$ to $A \times B$ itself. Start listing them and throwing away all that do not satisfy the def of function, like e.g. $\{ (0, a),(0, b) \}$.

Comment: Sidenote: it is more common to write $B^A$ instead of $A\to B$. Also observe that - using that notation - $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but  why does {(0,a),(0,b)} not satisfy the definition of a function? And if what I have got as the correct answer for $(A \to B)$ is wrong what is an example of an element that us in the set?

Comment: Because with $f = \{ (0,a),(0,b) \}$ we have $f(0)=a$ and $f(0)=b$ and a [function must be... "functional"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)): "a function is a relation between sets that associates to every element of a first set exactly one element of the second set. "

Comment: Ahh, of course, that makes sense now thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just reading it wrong, you should really understand the $\left\{(0,a),(1,b)\right\}$ as an encoding for the function $0$ goes to $a$ and $1$ goes to $b$. In the set you have given, there is a list of such encoding, which corresponds to all possible mappings. So $\left\{(0,a),(1,a)\right\}$ and $\left\{(0,a),(1,b)\right\}$ are two different functions.

Pay attention to the fact that each of the function is written $(0,\_),(1,\_)$, providing exactly one image for $0$ and one image for $1$, hence each element of $A$ gets a unique output